# Why Does F# Pattern Matching for a String Type Match a ReadOnlySpan<char>?

Tags: types, f#, pattern-matching

Let's say I wanted to find a particular `TryParse` method for a given type, namely the one that parses from a string. To my surprise, the following code returns 2 methods: one with a `string` as first parameter, but also one with a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` as first parameter.

I include this not-so-minimal example because it turns out to be somewhat hard to 'just' create `ReadOnlySpan`s in F# on the fly.

The second element in the result list is unexpected for me. How would I change the pattern matching at `[1]` to exclude it?

```ml
typeof<uint64>.GetMember("TryParse")
|> Seq.cast<MethodBase>
|> Seq.choose (fun m ->
    let parameterTypes =
        m.GetParameters()
        |> Array.map (fun p -> (p.ParameterType, p.Attributes))
    // [1]
    match parameterTypes with
    | [| (string, ParameterAttributes.None); (uint64, ParameterAttributes.Out) |] -> Some m
    | _ -> None)
|> Seq.toList
|> List.map (fun m -> (m.Name, m.GetParameters() |> Array.map (fun p -> p.ParameterType.FullName)))

(*
val it: (string * string array) list =
  [("TryParse", [|"System.String"; "System.UInt64&"|]);
   ("TryParse",
    [|"System.ReadOnlySpan`1[[System.Char, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]";
      "System.UInt64&"|])]
*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code finds both versions of `TryParse` because you've declared variables named `string` and `uint64`, which match on any value. To fix this, you need to compare against the actual types:

```ml
typeof<uint64>.GetMember("TryParse")
|> Seq.cast<MethodBase>
|> Seq.choose (fun m ->
    let parameterTypes =
        m.GetParameters()
        |> Array.map (fun p -> (p.ParameterType, p.Attributes))
    if parameterTypes = [| (typeof<string>, ParameterAttributes.None); (typeof<uint64>.MakeByRefType(), ParameterAttributes.Out) |] then
        Some m
    else
        None)
|> Seq.toList
|> List.map (fun m -> (m.Name, m.GetParameters() |> Array.map (fun p -> p.ParameterType.FullName)))
```

Note that you have to use `typeof` to get a type at runtime, and then call `MakeByRefType`.

Comment: This actually gives me the error 'Unexpected identifier in pattern. Expected infix operator, quote symbol or other token.' at the first `typeof<string>` in the pattern.

Comment: It's not a pattern at all. I'm using an `if` statement instead of a `match`. It's simpler for your problem, because you don't need pattern matching at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the full code.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an identifier in a pattern, you're not testing equality with an existing value (or type). Instead, you're defining a pattern that always matches, and giving the matched value the given name in the scope following the pattern.

To test for equality, you need to use a `when` guard instead:

```ml
    match parameterTypes with
    | [| (arg1, ParameterAttributes.None); (arg2, ParameterAttributes.Out) |]
        when arg1 = typeof<string> && arg2 = typeof<uint64>.MakeByRefType()
        -> Some m
    | _ -> None
```